# Where does the last parameter of the 'read' function in Linux kernel code point to?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In the `read` function prototype,

```
ssize_t read(struct file *filp, char __user *buff,size_t count, loff_t *offp);
```

where does the parameter `offp` point to?

What I understand from the below `write` function is that the parameter `ppos` points to the top of the data available in `deviceBuffer[]`, which is a global buffer in kernel space. Correct me if I am wrong.

How does this apply to `read` function ?

```
    static ssize_t mcspi_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t length, loff_t *ppos)

    {

    int maxbytes; /* maximum bytes that can be written */
    int bytes_to_write;
    int bytes_written = 0;
    //int i;

    maxbytes = BUFFER_SIZE - *ppos;
    if(maxbytes < length)
        bytes_to_write = maxbytes;
    else
        bytes_to_write = length;    
    bytes_written = bytes_to_write - copy_from_user(deviceBuffer + *ppos, buff, bytes_to_write);
    /*
       for(i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
       {
       printk(KERN_INFO "deviceBuffer[%d] = %x\n", i, deviceBuffer[i]);
       }
     */
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: %d bytes copied from user space\n", DEVICE_NAME, bytes_written);
    *ppos += bytes_written;

    return bytes_written;
}
```

Comment: @rodrigo: can you answer this question?

Comment: loff_t f_pos is nothing but the current reading or writing position. loff_t is a 64-bit value (long long in gcc terminology). The driver can read this value if it needs to know the current position in the file, but should never change it (read and write should update a position using the pointer they receive as the last argument instead of acting on filp->f_pos directly).

Comment: If I write some bytes to the device, is the driver responsible for updating the loff_t f_pos pointer?

Comment: Not necessary, if that there is any use case or that type of implementation is needed to keep track of the no of bytes written or read or if you want to check w.r.t no of bytes written/read can  based on size supported, then i guess driver has to take care. Please go through this link http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-7

Comment: Is there a way to return the number of bytes read/written without making use of loff_t f_pos?

Comment: Yes you can because while using read/write system call you pass the no of bytes needs to be read/write from/to the device(hardware), so you will try to read/write the asked no of bytes from/to the device. Accordingly return the no of bytes read/write.